# Modify array during iteration using collect

Tags: ruby

I am using the collect method to change the values of an array.  I am expecting the values of the array to be changed, but that's not happening.  In the code below, the array is initialized and the values are set to 1,2,3,4,5.  I print those values out to the screen to show what the values were before any changes.

After the original array is printed to the screen, I iterate through the array and change the value using the .collect method of anything enumerable.

When I print the value of 'arr' to the screen (see the last line of code below), it prints the exact same output as the beginning array!  In short, the value of 'arr' is the same before and after iterating over the array using collect.  I expect the first puts to be [1,2,3,4,5] and the second one to be [2,4,6,8,10].

Can you see what I am missing here???

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

puts arr # outputs 1 2 3 4 5
arr.collect { |x| x * 2 }
puts arr # still outputs 1 2 3 4 5 - not 2 4 5 8 10 as I expect
```

On a related note, can I change out collect with map (and map with collect) as I wish or are there differences?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In Ruby we don't usually do in-place change, but you can use `collect!` or `for loop`

Answer (score 7):

`collect` (an alias for `map`) does not modify the array in place.  It returns a new array.  So:

```
arr = arr.collect { |x| x * 2}
```

If you do want to modify the array in place, then use `collect!` (an alias for `map!`):

```
arr.collect! { |x| x * 2}
```

`map` is interchangeable with `collect`; `map!` is interchangeable with `collect!`